# Drop a column if the sum of that column equals 0 in R

Tags: r

I've created a for loop to iterate over each column in my train data set. It checks if the absolute sum of the columns value equals 0, if so, it will store the columns name in my list called "aux". At the end of the loop, I assign train to remove the columns that are in "aux".

Problem: I keep getting error message "Error in -aux : invalid argument to unary operator"

Notes about dataset: There are no NAs or NaN, all values are numeric. Currently it is a matrix, but I can transform into a dataframe if required.

```
aux = NULL #auxiliary vector
for(i in 1:ncol(train)){ #checking all columns of the df
  
  if(sum(abs(train[,i]))==0){ #if the sum of the column is zero (using absolute value to avoid problems where the positive and negative numbers sum to zero)
    
    aux = c(aux,i) #then store the number of that column
    
  }
  
}


train = train[,-aux] #and remove the columns
```

Comment: Your error suggests that `aux` is still `NULL`, so none of your columns add to 0. Note that you are summing absolute values, so `aux` would only get `i` appended if the whole column was zeros. In that case your whole loop could be replaced with `train[sapply(train, function(x) !all(x == 0)),]`

Comment: You are correct, I had noticed the problem right when you posted the comment haha. So now I have a new problem. With the last line of code ```train = train[,-aux]``` it is removing all variables in the dataset, instead of only the ones in aux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a loop, we can use `Filter`

```
Filter(function(x) sum(abs(x), na.rm = TRUE) > 0, train)
```

---

Or with `colSums`

```
train[colSums(abs(train), na.rm = TRUE) > 0]
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I used the second option you provided. Any idea how I can drop the same columns in my test dataset? I thought about making the for loop for that purpose, but that didn't work earlier, so I know I coded it wrong.

Comment: @RehankhanDaya You can get a logical vector with `i1 <- colSums(abs(train), na.rm = TRUE) > 0` and that can be used to get the column names.  i.e. `names(which(i1))` or for the columns droped `names(which(!i1))`